# How do i make a list of random unique numbers that avoid using numbers from an already existing list of random unique numbers?

Tags: python

I am trying to make a lottery machine that generate a list of 7 winning numbers and 3 bonus numbers from 1-34. I want the bonus numbers to never pick the same numbers as the winning numbers.

```
winning_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 34), 7)
bonus_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 34), 3)
```

Is there any command/code that can exclude the numbers already picked in the previous list?

Comment: Yes there is :)

Comment: What if you kept drawing numbers until there are no matches?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can Python generate a random number that excludes a set of numbers, without using recursion?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666661/can-python-generate-a-random-number-that-excludes-a-set-of-numbers-without-usin)

Comment: check out this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10666661/can-python-generate-a-random-number-that-excludes-a-set-of-numbers-without-usin

Comment: Note that if you want to include all the numbers up to and including 34, you should use `range(1, 35)`. https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range

Answer (score 2):

**`random` solution**

If you want to only use the `random` module, you can use:

```
import random

nums = random.sample(range(1,35), 10)

winning_numbers = nums[:7]
bonus_numbers = nums[7:]

>>> winning_numbers
[2, 23, 29, 34, 26, 16, 13]

>>> bonus_numbers
[8, 4, 19]
```

As `random.sample` is "Used for random sampling without replacement." (Quoted from the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/random.html))

**`numpy` solution**

You can also use `numpy`, as `numpy.random.choice` has a `replace` argument you can set to `false`. (I'm personally a fan or using `numpy` for random numbers, as it provides a lot more flexibility in more complex tasks than `random`)

```
import numpy as np

nums = np.random.choice(range(1,35), 10, replace=False)

winning_numbers = nums[:7]
bonus_numbers = nums[7:]


>>> winning_numbers
array([27,  4, 17, 30, 32, 21, 23])

>>> bonus_numbers
array([15, 13, 18])
```

Answer (score 2):

A small but not unimportant remark at the beginning:

**Whether you draw first 7 numbers and then 3 from the remaining ones, or 10 right away and split them into 7 winning numbers and 3 bonus numbers is absolutely equivalent in terms of probability**:

In the first case the probability for any number to become a bonus number is:

[image: first7then3]

And in the second:

[image: all10then3]

*Note that the reasoning for the probability of any number being a winning number is just the same.*

**Implementing the first case** is actually slightly longer, but still fairly simple when using `set` and [set operations](http://www.linuxtopia.org/online_books/programming_books/python_programming/python_ch16s03.html).
Here is how this could look:

```
import random

# set of all potential numbers to draw from
all_numbers = set(range(1,35))  
# draw the winners
winning_numbers = set(random.sample(all_numbers, 7)  
# subtract the winners
remaining_numbers = all_numbers-winning_numbers  
# draw the bonus from the remaining numbers:
bonus_numbers = set(random.sample(remaining_numbers, 3))
```

The **implementation of the 2nd case** is minimal and could look like this:

```
import random

drawn_numbers = random.sample(range(1,35), 10)
winning_numbers, bonus_numbers = drawn_numbers[:7], drawn_numbers[7:]
```

*Hope that helped and happy coding!*

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
import random
winning_numbers = random.sample(range(1, 34), 7)
bonus_numbers = []
while 1==1:
  num = random.randint(1,34)
  if len(bonus_numbers) == 3:
    break
  if num not in winning_numbers and num not in bonus_numbers:
    bonus_numbers.append(num)
```